# Yes another - The multi-part identifier "xxx" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Ok, here is my Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CS.CPL_Schedule_Id          AS CplScheduleId
    ,S.Schedule_Status_Id       AS ScheduleStatusId
    ,S.Record_Created           AS Created
FROM CPL_Schedule CS
    JOIN (
            SELECT TOP 1 CSL.CPL_Schedule_ID, CSL.Record_Created, CSL.Schedule_Status_Id
            FROM CPL_Schedule_Audit_Log CSL
            WHERE CSL.CPL_Schedule_ID = CS.CPL_Schedule_ID
            ORDER BY Record_Created DESC
        ) S
        ON S.CPL_Schedule_ID = CS.CPL_Schedule_ID
WHERE 
    CS.Exhibitor_Id = 1
```

And I am getting the error on this line `WHERE CSL.CPL_Schedule_ID = CS.CPL_Schedule_ID`

> The multi-part identifier "CS.CPL_Schedule_ID" could not be bound.

To me it looks like this is saying that nested query does not know about CS, is that true?  What am I missing here?  Help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, you need `cross apply` instead of `join`, and don't need `ON` hence.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CS.CPL_Schedule_Id          AS CplScheduleId
    ,S.Schedule_Status_Id       AS ScheduleStatusId
    ,S.Record_Created           AS Created
FROM CPL_Schedule CS
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 CSL.CPL_Schedule_ID, CSL.Record_Created, CSL.Schedule_Status_Id
            FROM CPL_Schedule_Audit_Log CSL
            WHERE CSL.CPL_Schedule_ID = CS.CPL_Schedule_ID
            ORDER BY Record_Created DESC
        ) S
WHERE 
    CS.Exhibitor_Id = 1
```

Comment: This is fantastic, how did I not know about CROSS APPLY?!